# How to correctly specify path in aws ssm get-parameters-by-path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

With aws cli I can successfully create parameter in AWS Paramater Store and retrieve it using get-parameters.

Example:

```
anarinsky:~> aws ssm put-parameter --name /IAD/ERP/Oracle/addUsers --value "Milana,Mariana,Mark,Miguel" --type StringList --region us-east-1
anarinsky:~> aws ssm get-parameters --name "/IAD/ERP/Oracle/addUsers" --region us-east-1

{"Parameters": [{ "Name": "/IAD/ERP/Oracle/addUsers","Type": "StringList","Value": "Milana,Mariana,Mark,Miguel" } ], "InvalidParameters": []
}
```

How to retrieve the same parameter using aws ssm get-parameters-by-path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To retrieve by path the command is

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/IAD/ERP/Oracle/" --region us-east-1
```

Comment: May also wanna add `--recursive` in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into issues when specifying a partial path.  I needed to add the `--recursive` flag in order to match in this case.

For example, in a set of parameters having database connection information, for several databases, this query returns `{ parameters[] }`

```
aws ssm get-paramters-by-path /prod/appA/db
```

whereas the query for for our reporting center database (the last node in the path) works ok:

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /prod/appA/db/rc
```

To get all the parameters under a key that is not the end node, add --recursive, such that

```
aws ssm get-paramters-by-path --path /prod/ --recursive
```

returns all production parameters.

Bonus tip: add `--query 'Parameters[].[Name,Value]'` to select just the ones you want, and `--with-decryption` if any are stored as `SecureString`.

Answer (score -1):

This is the documentation link  for your question

"https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters-by-path.html"

aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/site/newyork/department/" --region any